# Multi-Level Menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I've been scratching my head on how to get this dynamic menu working in a cleaner way than I currently do, I currently receive a list of menu items as a flat XML structure.

I've created an object below illustrating how the data will look inside an object, it has a parent-child relationship for each menu item (I've indented for ease of reading)

```
let Menu = [
  {
    DisplayName  : "Menu1",
    href         : "Menu1.aspx",
    MenuID       : "1",
    ParentMenuID : "?",
    Position     : "1",
    UserTypeCode : "99"
  },
      {
        DisplayName  : "Menu-1-1",
        href         : "Menu1.aspx",
        MenuID       : "2",
        ParentMenuID : "1",
        Position     : "1",
        UserTypeCode : "99"
      },
      {
        DisplayName  : "Menu-1-2",
        href         : "Menu1.aspx",
        MenuID       : "3",
        ParentMenuID : "1",
        Position     : "2",
        UserTypeCode : "99"
      },
  {
    DisplayName  : "Menu2",
    href         : "Menu2.aspx",
    MenuID       : "4",
    ParentMenuID : "?",
    Position     : "2",
    UserTypeCode : "99"
  },
      {
        DisplayName  : "Menu2-1",
        href         : "Menu1.aspx",
        MenuID       : "5",
        ParentMenuID : "4",
        Position     : "1",
        UserTypeCode : "99"
      },
      {
        DisplayName  : "Menu2-2",
        href         : "Menu1.aspx",
        MenuID       : "6",
        ParentMenuID : "4",
        Position     : "2",
        UserTypeCode : "99"
      },
          {
            DisplayName  : "Menu2-2-1",
            href         : "Menu1.aspx",
            MenuID       : "7",
            ParentMenuID : "6",
            Position     : "1",
            UserTypeCode : "99"
          }
];
```

I would like to know how I could dynamically create the menu object (using a recursive function I believe would be ideal) without my current somewhat messy solution of requiring a different function for each level of my menu, Here is what my code looks like at the minute, It is limited to only 3 levels of menu's

What I desire is a nice function where it will accept any number of menu levels

```
function createRoot(){

    // Initially map all root elements
    Menu.map((item, index) => {

        if (item.ParentMenuID === "?"){

            // If the the next menu item is a child of this root
            if (Menu[index+1].ParentMenuID === item.MenuID){

                // Generate boilerplate dropdown code + then retrieve it's children
                htmlStr += `<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="test" data-menuID="`+item.MenuID+`" data-menuitem="`+item.href+`" href="#">`+item.DisplayName+`<span class="caret"></a>`
                    htmlStr += `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`
                        GetLevel1(item);
                    htmlStr += `</ul>`
                htmlStr += `</li>`

            // Otherwise it's just a normal menu item
            } else {
                htmlStr += `<li><a class="test" data-menuID="`+item.MenuID+`" data-menuitem="`+item.href+`" href="#">`+item.DisplayName+`</a></li>`
            }
        }


    });

    $('#user-menu-list').html(htmlStr);

      // Setup event on list items
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
}

function GetLevel1(item){

    Menu.map((subItem, index) => {

        if (index < Menu.length-1){
        console.log(index);
            // If the current item is a child of the root
            if (subItem.ParentMenuID === item.MenuID){
                // If the the next item is a child of this root
                if (Menu[index+1].ParentMenuID === subItem.MenuID){
                    htmlStr += `<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="test" data-menuID="`+subItem.MenuID+`" data-menuitem="`+subItem.href+`" href="#">`+subItem.DisplayName+`<span class="caret"></a>`
                        htmlStr += `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`
                            GetLevel2(subItem);
                        htmlStr += `</ul>`
                    htmlStr += `</li>`
                } else {
                    htmlStr += `<li><a class="test" data-menuID="`+subItem.MenuID+`" data-menuitem="`+subItem.href+`" href="#">`+subItem.DisplayName+`</a></li>`
                }
            }

        }


    });
}

function GetLevel2(item){

    Menu.map((subItem, index) => {

        console.log("INDEX: "+index);
        // If the current item is a child of the root
        if (subItem.ParentMenuID === item.MenuID){
            htmlStr += `<li><a class="test" data-menuID="`+subItem.MenuID+`" data-menuitem="`+subItem.href+`" href="#">`+subItem.DisplayName+`</a></li>`
        }
    });
}

createRoot();
```

Here is a full pastebin link with my menu working at the minute: http://pastebin.com/ektBQ7kd

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A recursive function seems good here.

Comment: Thats what i'm after really but can't figure out how I would do it for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recursive abilities are a bit rusty this can be improved,
I would do something like this,
First go over all the menu, add children menus to their parents.

After phase one complete and I have menus and submenus in one object, you can do recursive again and build the menu.

Something like this:

```js
var Menu = [{
  DisplayName: "Menu1",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "1",
  ParentMenuID: "?",
  Position: "1",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu-1-1",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "2",
  ParentMenuID: "1",
  Position: "1",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu-1-2",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "3",
  ParentMenuID: "1",
  Position: "2",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu2",
  href: "Menu2.aspx",
  MenuID: "4",
  ParentMenuID: "?",
  Position: "2",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu2-1",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "5",
  ParentMenuID: "4",
  Position: "1",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu2-2",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "6",
  ParentMenuID: "4",
  Position: "2",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}, {
  DisplayName: "Menu2-2-1",
  href: "Menu1.aspx",
  MenuID: "7",
  ParentMenuID: "6",
  Position: "1",
  UserTypeCode: "99"
}];

var main = [];

function getSiblins(currentNode, currentId) {
  if (!currentId) {
    currentNode.children = currentNode.children || new Array();
    return getSiblins(currentNode, currentNode.MenuID)
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < Menu.length; j++) {
      if (Menu[j].ParentMenuID == currentId) {
        currentNode.children.push(Menu[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  if (currentNode.ParentMenuID == "?") {
    //root menu
    main.push(currentNode);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < Menu.length; i++)
  getSiblins(Menu[i]);

function prepareMenu(currentMenu) {
  var appendHtml = "<li>" + currentMenu.DisplayName + "</li>"
  for (var i = 0; i < currentMenu.children.length; i++) {
    appendHtml = appendHtml + "<ul class='children'>" + prepareMenu(currentMenu.children[i]) + "</ul>";
  }

  return appendHtml;
}

var menuHtml = "";
for (var j = 0; j < main.length; j++) {
  menuHtml += prepareMenu(main[j]);
}

document.getElementById("finalMenu").innerHTML = menuHtml;
```

```css
.children li{
  color: blue;
}

.children .children li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="finalMenu">

</ul>
```